# Repeated git log entry after merge failed

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a git-svn repository and wanted to merge a branch onto master. To do so, I performed the following steps, starting on the branch:

```
git commit -m "my commit message"    # commit the changes on the branch
git checkout master                  # change to the branch I want to changes to be merged in
git svn rebase                       # update the repository
git merge --no-ff -m "my commit message" # merge the branch onto master
```

But at this phase I got the following error:

```
Auto-merging <file>
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in home/httpd/html/data/php/includes/Processes.inc.php
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Then I went to fix the conflict on one offending file (several other files were merged fine), and repeated the last command, i.e.

```
git merge --no-ff -m "my commit message" # merge the branch onto master
```

But got the following error:

```
fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.
```

Ok, so then made a commit as the error message suggest,

```
git commit -m "my commit message"
```

After that, I looked in `git log` and saw my given commit message twice in the output!

The very last commit does not contain ANY change, while all the changes (including the file with the conflict) are part of the second-to-last commit.

I have three questions:

1. What has happened above exactly to create TWO identical commits with the identical commit message?
2. Is there a 'simple' way to safely fix that? (Could I just do a `git reset HEAD~1` to get rid of the last, empty commit?)
3. What is the 'standard' procedure/list of commands in case a conflict occurrs after a merge? Should I do a `git merge` then, or a `git commit` or something else?

If something is unclear, please provide comments so I can update the question and make it clearer.

Comment: Are the two commits *really* identical? Use `git log -p` to inspect what changes each has produced.

Comment: No, the 'commit messages' are identical. Not the commits. But I want to know, how this happend, and how to prevent this behavior from happening again, in case I get a conflict after a merge. How to proceed after a conflict from a merge?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you did the right thing.  Probably your `git log` output is showing you both the commit on your branch and the merge commit on master.  Try using `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` which should let you see which branch each commit is on.

Diffing the merge commit against the branch commit should show only the changes you made to resolve the merge, or none if the merge commit is identical to your branch commit.  But diffing the merge commit against `git-svn` should show the full merged changes.

If this is the case, then there's nothing to fix - there's no need to get rid of the old branch and its commit, although it does look confusing in `git log` if you're not using the `--graph` option.